# which urls need to be accessible for android developemnt

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am working behind a strict proxy and struggling with identification of URLs which need to be accessible for android developement.

I know for SDK updates `https://dl-ssl.google.com/` should be accessible.
I need answer to following queries:

1. What are the URLs for resolving dependencies using gradle also for updating gradle itself?
2. Are there any additional urls apart from sdk update and gradel dependencies which need to be accssible?

Comment: you might need maven as well. And some additional repositories depending on the dependencies you wish to add, as some developers use personal repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler.html) provides with requirement for usage of gradle in android studio. with this following are answers to queries:

1. Following are the urls need to be accessible for basic gradle functionality:

   - https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
   - https://jcenter.bintray.com/
2. Apart from these any URL required for access of custom libraries hosted on other then default location.

Getting exceptional access from network admin team for said URLs will solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

After a quick search,I also found below urls-

1. http://download.gradle.com
2. http://services.gradle.com
3. https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
4. https://jcenter.bintray.com/
5. http://repo.jfrog.org

May be these will work.

Answer (score 0):

if your'e running gradle behind a proxy. try adding the proxy settings to your gradle.properties file e.g.

```
   systemProp.http.proxyUser=myusername
   systemProp.http.proxyPort=yourport
   systemProp.http.proxyPassword=proxypasswordhere
   systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy url/ip here
```

Comment: This wont help as proxy will block said urls regardless of who the client is.