# How to download gradle manually?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm using Android Studio version 1.4 and stuck at "Gradle: resolve dependencies ':app:_releaseCompile'"

I think it cause by proxy (I don't have access to proxy) so i want to know how to download gradle maunally

I've tried all method that I found changing properties file, edit parameters but won't work anyway.

Error log:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugUnitTestCompile'.
   > Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
     Required by:
         prototype1:app:unspecified
      > Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
         > Could not get resource 'jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
               > Connection to jcenter.bintray.com refused
```

Comment: I think this question is answered many times here.

Comment: May be [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523707/which-urls-need-to-be-accessible-for-android-developemnt) will help you. It's not exactly what you asked for but something similar.

Comment: I know that this question is asked and answer many times here but I tried all method I found but it won't work

Comment: `"so i want to know how to download gradle maunally"`, do it from [here](https://gradle.org/gradle-download/)

Comment: and where do i install it ?

Comment: under linux it is `~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/`

Comment: under .gredle there's only caches, daemon and native folder why i have no wrapper folder?

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32602039/3922207

Comment: My problem is solved thanks!